# What is the output of running cat swapfile?

Tags: swap, cat

Why when I run `sudo cat swapfile` I get a bunch of unknown characters. What do these characters mean? Plus my keyboard then types these unknown characters. As a side note this is an active swap file. A little snippet of these characters can be seen as:

```
����� @�p9�f��SWAPSPACE2
```

Comment: And what you expect? It is raw data for/from RAM. But if you want more pretty output you may use `sudo hexdump -C swapfile` :)

Comment: Very unhelpful... I was wondering more of what the data meant not what your opinion was...

Comment: @NerdOfCode N0rbert just told you... It's raw memory. Edit: Oh wait, did some comments get deleted? Sorry, that always trips me up.

Comment: After reading this: https://www.centos.org/docs/5/html/5.2/Deployment_Guide/ch-swapspace.html you will know WHAT swap is and then I think you can answer your own question.

Comment: Worth noting that � is a replacement for a character that cannot be rendered, so it doesn't tell us what character is acutally in the swapfile. You could use `hexdump` instead of `cat` to get the actual data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swapfiles, you already probably know, contain data swapped out from RAM. So whatever data there is, it belongs to some process. What exactly that may be - depends on multiple factors and what process that data belongs to originally.

Swap files and partitions do have certain filesystem in place there, so considering the fact that we see `SWAPSPACE2` string, this can either be part of that filesystem header or some process had that string in their memory which was swapped out.

Comment: Very helpful answer, I’m very happy with the wording too!!!

Answer (score 3):

The output of running `sudo cat swapfile` is

```
����� @�p9�f��SWAPSPACE2
```

…at least on your system at that time and with this specific terminal configuration.

<sup>Sorry, couldn't resist to give this terrible literal answer to the terrible question. Please restate your question to ask what you *actually* want to know.</sup>